# Selenium Firefox Unable to add extension

Tags: c#, selenium

I am trying to add the latest version of AdBlock to the latest version of Firefox with Selenium.  The browser loads fine, no exceptions, but AdBlock is not being properly installed, when I check the extensions in the browser it is not there.

```
public static FirefoxDriver CreateFirefoxDriver(string driverPath, string binaryPath)
{
    var profile = new FirefoxProfile();
    profile.AddExtension(@"C:\Users\david\source\repos\TestingApp\TestingApp\bin\Debug\selenium\browsers\firefox\extensions\adblock_plus-3.3.1-an+fx.xpi");
    profile.SetPreference("permissions.default.image", 2);
    var options = new FirefoxOptions();
    options.Profile = profile;
    var service = FirefoxDriverService.CreateDefaultService(driverPath);
    service.FirefoxBinaryPath = binaryPath;
    var driver = new FirefoxDriver(service, options);
    return driver;
}
```

When I add the extension manually with the same xpi file it works fine.

> Selenium Nuget Version 3.14.0 (latest)
>
> geckodriver 0.23.0 win64 (latest)
>
> Firefox 62.0.3 64-bit (latest)
>
> AdBlock 3.3.1 (latest)

**Updates:**

Tried the newest version of uBlock xpi file, also is not showing up in my extensions with no exception to help me diagnose what is going wrong.  Can easily add the same extension manually.

I tried using Firefox 61 and 60, still having the same issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally was able to solve the problem.  I kept trying older versions of Firefox and eventually 58.0.2 worked.  I can't seem to find a list of compatible versions with geckodriver on their github page.