# Selenium Firefox not adding extensions

Tags: c#, selenium

I'm trying to get ublock installed on Firefox with Selenium. The problem is, the extension won't load. The browser loads fine but does not add the extension.

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.AddExtension("ublock_origin-1.17.4-an+fx.xpi");
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions
{
    Profile = profile
};
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

I've seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52788581/selenium-firefox-unable-to-add-extension) but I don't want to use an old version of firefox, and i haven't seen any other fix for it.

Currently using **v0.23.0** of geckodriver for win64.

How can I add extensions to firefox with selenium? *(without using an old version)*

Comment: Looks like you are not giving the complete path to your extension

Comment: @SnR Tried with full path too, no change.

Comment: What version of selenium webdriver are you using?

Comment: @PrasanthG The latest version, v3.141.0. Selenium webdriver hasn't been updated for 15 months and this question is 12 months old.

Comment: You can try the selenium 4.x which is in the alpha stage. Just use the FirefoxDriver class and call InstallAddOnFromFile and pass your extension's file path. It should work

Answer (score 1):

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions
{
    Profile = profile
};
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
firefoxDriver.InstallAddOnFromFile("ublock_origin-1.17.4-an+fx.xpi"); // Dear Wizard, this is the magic
```

Use Selenium 4.X and use the `FirefoxDriver.InstallAddOnFromFile` method instead of the the `FirefoxOptions.AddExtension`

Comment: This method does neither exist in version 3 nor 4.x ?

Comment: @Andre InstallAddOnFromFile is a method of FirefoxDriver in 4.0.0-rc-1. The code should read `FirefoxDirver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);`.

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting out the options part, see if that makes a difference:

```
FirefoxProfile profile = new FirefoxProfile();
profile.AddExtension(*file path*);
FirefoxOptions options = new FirefoxOptions();
options.Profile = profile;
IWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(options);
```

Comment: This is literally the same as what I have, mine is just simplified. It won't make any difference